# unable to upgrade pip on Python 3.4

Tags: upgrade, python, pip

I saw the large number of posts already posted; however, none of them quite have this same error. So I wanted to re-post this. I am running the following command: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/b6/ac/7015eb97dc749283ffdec1c3a88ddb8ae03b8fad0f0e611408f196358da3/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=297dbd16ef53bcef0447d245815f5144
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Can't roll back pip; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/Usass/.pip/pip.log
```

I have python3.4 and I am trying to run this command from bash on windows. The end goal is to download **Jupyter**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade pip to latest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712339/how-to-upgrade-pip-to-latest)

Comment: `pip` is for python2 . Python3.x : Install `pip3`

Comment: I have tried pip3 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`

The last line in the error log clearly says that it is an issue of inadequate permissions.
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip'`