# "Errno 13 Permission denied" for pip and anaconda

Tags: permissions, python, pip, anaconda

I was trying to update anaconda by:

```
conda update conda
```

it returns:

```
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Then I found out that the same happens for pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

returns:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/pip'
```

Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: What is this output of this command : `ls -ld ~/anaconda3` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to upgrade pip on Python 3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909358/unable-to-upgrade-pip-on-python-3-4)

Comment: Solved with [`pip install <package> --user`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087199/4970442).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to conda's [github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3448#issuecomment-282467541) page:

Its may because of `~/anaconda3`'s owner and group. You can change this directories owner and group by this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/anaconda3
```

---

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441772) answer:

If the above command not works for you, this one may be helpful:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda update conda
```

Comment: @VIN I'm glad I could help you, If this answer be helpful please accept it.