# how to upgrade pip to version >> 9.0.1 ? (pip install --upgrade pip gives 'cannot import name main' error)

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, pip

I have pip 8.1 installed and I wanted to upgrade to > 9.0.1 (to install matplotlib for python 2.7).  I saw [How to upgrade pip to latest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712339/how-to-upgrade-pip-to-latest) and did

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

but after than, if I type `pip --version`, I get

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

This had I experienced before and I knew the solution(Hmm. sounds like German word order..:)) , so I did

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python-pip --reinstall
```

and then I type `pip --version`  and get

```
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

This is back to 8.1.1. How can I upgrade to newest version?

ADD : I'm using 16.04.5 LTS. This in system environment.(ok in python 2.7 virtual environment)

Comment: You should tell us your release of Ubuntu.  `pip --version` shows 18.1 from my Ubuntu release, so older? My guess is 16.04 LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python-pip)  but we shouldn't be guessing....

Comment: @guiverc I'm using 16.04.5 LTS. This in system environment.(ok in python 2.7 virtual environment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the `pip` [installed by](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#debian-ubuntu) `apt` [conflicts with](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) the standard `pip` package

The easiest solution is to only install the standard `pip`:

1. Uninstall `pip` by running the following until nothing happens:

   ```bsh
   sudo python -m pip uninstall pip
   ```
2. Uninstall `apt` `pip`

   ```bsh
   sudo apt-get remove python-pip
   ```
3. Download the `pip` boot-strap from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
4. Install standard `pip`

   ```bsh
   python get-pip.py
   ```

NB: replace `python` with `python3` if you're using Python 3, but the OP wants `matplotlib` for Python 2

---

The main [difference](https://wiki.debian.org/Python#Deviations_from_upstream) between the `apt` `pip` and the standard `pip` is that `--user` is the default on `apt`, meaning packages will be installed to the user's packages directory: eg "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages". Standard `pip` will default to installing to the system packages directory. *Edit: [`pip` v20](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id60) will install to the user directory if it doesn't have permissions to edit the system directory*

Also, the `apt` `pip` tends to be *many* versions behind, lacking many features and bug-fixes that are in the current standard `pip` (such as installation from private repositories, [PEP-517](https://medium.com/@grassfedcode/pep-517-and-518-in-plain-english-47208ca8b7a6) support, command-line autocompletion)

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing things without upgrading pip but will try your method later. You gave me some good infos.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```