# Get "EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" error when trying to pip install any package

Tags: package-management, permissions, python, pip

When I try to `pip install` any package I'm getting this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:   
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy'  
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

When I try to `sudo pip install` anything I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
farzand@farzand-linux:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different pip packages in Ubuntu 18.04: *python-pip* (for Python 2.x) and *python3-pip* (for Python 3.x). To install packages that are compatible with the default Python version in 18.04 you need to install python3-pip.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

You can also install numpy with either:

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy # for Python 3.x
```

or

```
sudo apt install python-numpy  # for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier
```

Note the `python-` and `python3-` convention for prefacing package names of Python 2.x and Python 3.x packages in the default Ubuntu repositories.

<sub>[How to upgrade pip to latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/712339/)</sub>